# Проблемы с SocketIO по протоколу WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket, flask, socket.io

Доброе день.

Была давняя задумка сделать свой чат, со своим публичным API, и всё это максимально оптимизировать.

Пробовал работать с `Aiohttp` и `AsyncIO` ничего хорошего у меня с этим не получилось. Вернулся к истокам, а именно к `Flask`

Чат работал так, как должен любой чат: передавал сообщения, которые заносились в базу эвентов на `Redis` и второй поток каждый раз при новом эвенте предупреждал сервер и тот делал ответ сокет-клиентам на сам чат.

Всё бы идеально, но я не использовал протокол `WebSocket` и весь Сокет-сервер работал в `threading async mode`. Я заметил, что после 5-6 подключенных клиентов сервер просто перестал отвечать и постоянно держал клиентов на подключении в режиме вечного ожидания

Решил попробовать ещё раз всмотреться в доки, нашёл другие режимы работы, среди которых были `eventlet` и `gevent`

Проблемы с которыми столкнулся:

- `eventlet` Клиент подключался по `Websocket` мог делать запросы НА сервер, но обратно он ничего не получал.
- `gevent` Вроде как работает и реквест и респонс по `WebSocket` но ответ приходилось ждать около 10-20 секунд.

**UPDATE:** Если при `gevent` отправить еще одно сообщение в очередь, то моментально придет прошлое ¯_(ツ)_/¯

**Клиент на JS:**

```html
<script>
      var namespace = ''
      var socket = io.connect('http://weetway.ru:5000' + namespace, {transports: ['websocket']})
 socket.on( 'connect', function() {
      //socket.emit('getTs', {'ts': '0'})
        var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault()
          let user_name = encodeURI($( 'input.username' ).val())
          let user_input = encodeURI($( 'input.message' ).val())
            console.log(user_name)
            console.log(user_input)
          socket.emit( 'sendMessage', {
            'name' : user_name,
            'message' : user_input
          })
          // empty the input field
          $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
        } )
      } )

      // capture message
      socket.on('getTs'), function (ts) {
          ts = ts
      }
      socket.on('polling', function( msg ) {
          console.log('New Event -> ' + msg)
          //msg = JSON.parse(msg)
          if (typeof msg.username !== 'undefined') {
          //console.log('Gotcha!')
          $('h1').remove()
          $('div.message_holder').append('<div id="ts-' + msg.timestamp + '" class="msg_bbl"><b style="color: #000">' + msg.username + ':</b> ' + msg.message + '</div>')
          $('#ts-' + msg.timestamp).ScrollTo();
          }
      })
    </script>
```

**Сервер на Python:**

```
@pollingup._polling.on('polling')
    def view(event):
        event = str(event)
        event = urllib.parse.unquote(event)
        print(newEvent(str(event)))
        socketio.emit('polling', eval(event))

@socketio.on('sendMessage')
    def newMessage(json):
        chat.sendMessage(name=json['name'], message=json['message'])
```

Если нужно, то можете зайти для просмотра с открытой консолью `F12` - http://weetway.ru:5000

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: В браузерах уже давно есть `WebSocket`.

Comment: @And ... На секундочку, а чем ещё, по вашему мнению, `socket.io` с транспортом `"websocket"` может пользоваться?

Comment: @D-side, я к тому, что нет смысла использовать библиотеку `isocket`, ибо уже есть встроенная поддержка в браузере, а на сервере, все делается стандартно.

Comment: @And `socket.io` она называется. Так бы и было, если бы `socket.io` был практически голой обёрткой над WS, но у него и собственных фишек хватает.